# Django-Cms 2.4 South Migration on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-south, django-cms, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app (still in development) built with Django-Cms 2.4 and its other dependencies, the problem i'm having is that during deployment to AWS Beanstalk Environment, the 01_syncdb command below fails whenever i add a new app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

## In the .config file

I have the in the container commands:

```
01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only = True
02_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only = True
```

## log

```
2013-08-20 10:21:46,812 [DEBUG] (19029 MainThread) [commandWrapper.py-60] [root commandWrapper main] Command result: {'status': 'FAILURE', 'results': [{'status': 'FAILURE', 'config_set': u'Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild', 'returncode': 1, 'events': [], 'msg': 'Error occurred during build: Command 01_syncdb failed\n'}], 'api_version': '1.0'}
```

What could be wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To others that encounter this problem, you might want to check if you have `mysql-python` (or whatever database driver compatible with the database your project is using) included in your `requirements.txt` so that the system will know that you need this installed in your environment. Django won't be able to communicate with the database without this package.

I also predict that your second command (`02_migrate`) will fail since the `migrate` command will not be recognized by django-admin.py. Use the following instead

```
02_migrate:
     command: "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
```

Comment: I am new to South, and from what I read in the tutorial you have to call `python manage.py schemamigration --auto` and then `python manage.py migrate myapp` right? Why isn't it included

Comment: `schemamigration` creates a migration file which basically serves as the 'blueprint' on how to migrate the schema. This means that once the migration file is created (which you usually do in your local environment and push/upload it with the project) , there is generally no longer any need to call the command (`schemamigration`) again.

The `migrate` command basically migrates the schema based on these created migration files and the current status of the database.